# Get-Process doesn't work with one user but works fine with another user

Tags: powershell

```
get-process -ComputerName Win2012r2
get-process : Couldn't connect to remote machine.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-process -ComputerName 10.10.1.54
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

This works fine with my personal account but doesn't work with the computer service account.

So I know it's not a DNS issue.
RemoteRegistry should be running on remote machines because my personal account works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Computer Service account does not have the correct permissions for the remote machine (`Win2012r2`).

You can fix this by granting the correct permissions on the remote machine.

As show on [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx), you can grant full Local Administrator on the remote machine, or grant limited permissions for Remote PowerShell sessions by running the following command, accepting the dialog, and adding the account.

`Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -showSecurityDescriptorUI`